# Creating class and parsing JSON array on android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have the following JSON output example:

[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last name": "BBB",
    "courses": [
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
       "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last name": "BBB",
    "courses": []
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last name": "BBB",
    "courses": [
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last name": "BBB",
    "courses": [
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "grade": "90"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need help with creating class and parsing this JSON.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Course {
    private String name;
    private String grade;
}

public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
}
```

this site very helpful in such things - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!